# Update Keycloak user data based on data present in Identity Provider token

Tags: keycloak

I am running Keycloak as an Identity Broker, with one Identity Provider configured.

When a user with a valid token from my IdP accesses my application for the first time, that user is created in Keycloak with information from the token.  This includes email, username, firstName and lastName.  Keycloak then issues its token with that user information.

When the same user logs in subsequently, the Keycloak token is crafted from the user information in the Keycloak database.

My question is this: if a user changes his lastName at the IdP, how can I configure Keycloak to automatically update its records to match the information on the IdP token?

Comment: There should be hooks where you can perform sync between external IDP user data and internal Keycloak user representation. You should check documentation or sources.
At least implementing event listener (KC should fire event on IDP login) could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we came up with was to implement our own `IdentityProvider` that extends Keycloak's `OIDCIdentityProvider` to override the `updateBrokeredUser` method.  In this overridden method, we set the `userModel`'s lastName to that from the `BrokeredIdentityContext` (which came from the token from the IdP).  Like this:

```
@Override
public void updateBrokeredUser(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, 
        UserModel user, BrokeredIdentityContext context) {
    user.setFirstName(context.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(context.getLastName());
    // etc for other user attributes
}
```

The default implementation of this `updateBrokeredUser` method is a no-op, so it's pretty clear to me that Keycloak intended for this to be overridden to do things like this.

Our custom identity provider class gets wired in via the usual way using the provider / provider factory mechanism.

Comment: But this doesn't add the ability to get updates from the IDP, or make the SP fetch for updates when generating token, right? It seems this would be triggered only when the SP updates its data by a user login

Answer (score 5):

Configure your realm's 'Sync mode' to force and the Attribute Import mappers of your IdP's 'Sync Mode Override' to force/inherit. During each authentication if there is a change at IdP end, the data will be updated at KeyCloak end

The sync mode determines when user data will be synced using the mappers. 'force' to always update the user during every login with this identity provider.

Comment: This can also be done at the identity provider level, not necessarily at realm level

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to implement your own `IdentityProvider` to achieve that. Instead just add a mapper of type `Attribute Importer` to the identity provider. For the case of taking the last name, you can get the the attribute value out of the `profile` client scope that an OpenID provider should provide. Just set `Claim` to `given_name` and `User Attribute Name` to `firstName` as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSvff.png). Each new login with the brokered account will then cause Keycloak to update the account. (tested on Keycloak 7.0.1)

Comment: The question is not how to update the profile information on the **first login** but how to keep it updated afterwards.

Comment: Well, that solution will work not only on **first login** but also on every **subsequent login** (which is what I meant with **new login**). However, if the requirement is to have a trigger caused as soon as the user updates his profile in the IdP then it requires some adjustment in the IdP itself (which I wouldn't assume you have access to). Please correct me if I got it wrong.

Comment: @Martin I tried your method with a google identity provider and it did not work (keycloak  8.0.1) although it seemd promising because I have the exact problem of my user names not updating...
Any idea of what could go wrong ?

Comment: @Grammy can you give the configuration of the mapper? For me it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/iYVFXyf.png

Comment: @Martin I have the exact same mapper + another for first name but the user data stays unchanged in keylcoak when it changes in the identity provider. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Martin can you please explain how can the IDP (Azue) be configured to actively push updates to the SP (Keycloak), or some direction of what I should be looking for?